# Restore all expanded node after file opening without collapsing whole tree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am new to Java Swing and need your advice on the following issue to resolve the issue.

I'm trying to  reset a specific node  that was expanded before loading a new value in the tree table,  the new values will be loaded without collapsing the whole tree.

The problem is that each time I open a file via open menu to load a new value in the tree table. Once I clicked the button "ok" in the open dialog, the new values are loaded but whole tree is automatically collapsed while executing the following line:

```
 buttonOk.setText("OK");
 buttonOk.addActionListener(evt -> buttonOkActionPerformed());

 private void buttonOkActionPerformed() {// GEN- 
 FIRST:event_buttonOkActionPerformed

    final OpenFiles selectedFiles = new OpenFiles(
        new File(textParamDir.getText(), comboFile.getSelectedItem().toString());

    switch (controller.performActionOpen(selectedFiles)) {
    case OPEN_FAILED:
    new JCBPOptionPane("Cannot Open. ", WARNING, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, new String[] { "OK" });
    controller.setControllerAfterDialog();
    break;
    case ERROR_INTERNAL:
    new JCBPOptionPane("Internal Error", WARNING, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, new String[] { "OK" });
    break;
    case OPEN_SUCCESSFUL:
    openMRPDialog.setVisible(false);
    openMRPDialog.dispose();
    break;
    case ERROR_NOVALUES:
    new JCBPOptionPane("No file chosen", WARNING, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, new String[] { "OK" });
    controller.setControllerAfterDialog();
    break;
    default:
    }   
}// GEN-LAST:event_buttonOkActionPerformed
```

Here, I need to keep a node as expanded that user expanded before opening the file to reload a value.

While debugging, the class EventDispatchThread lead to collapse the whole tree after loading a new value in the treetable.

Can anyone tell me how to refresh a node of a tree without collapsing the whole tree?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You're going to have to [expand the node yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042356/how-to-expand-to-specific-treenode-in-jtree) in the `JButton` `ActionListener` after you update the new values.